# Dart polymer, access Custom attribute return null in script

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

I send a client as a parameter to custom client-followup-detail (in home.html) and show their information in "client_followup_detail.html", but when I try to access the client attribute from "client_followup_detail.dart" exception occurs.

home.html

```dart
<template repeat="{{index in extraTabsIndex}}">
  <template if="{{activeTab == index}}">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <p>
         <client-followup-detail client="{{clientSelect}}"></client-followup-detail>
      </p>
    </div>
 </template>
```

client_followup_detail.html

```dart
<td>{{client.state}}</td>
<td>{{client.cellphone}}</td>
<td>{{client.lastContactDate}}</td>
```

client_followup_detail.dart

```dart
  @published Client client;  
  ClientFollowupDetail.created() : super.created() {
    eventBus = getInstanceEventBus();
    print(client.names);    //  client null
  }
```

error:

```dart
Exception: The null object does not have a getter 'names'.
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'names'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
```

Comment: The interesting part would probably be home.dart

Comment: Where comes the `clientSelect` from? Can you try to put your `{{clientSelect}}` outside the `<client-follow-detail>` tag and check what output it produces on your page (like `<p>{{clientSelect}}</p>).

Answer (score 3):

The ClientFollowupDetail instance might not be fully initialized by polymer.

It may help to move your `create` code into an override of `ready`:

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
  eventBus = getInstanceEventBus();
  print(client.names);
}
```